# Which one I should use in Clojure? go block or thread?

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I want to see the intrinsic difference between a thread and a long-running go block in Clojure. In particular, I want to figure out which one I should use in my context.

I understand if one creates a go-block, then it is managed to run in a so-called thread-pool, the default size is 8. But `thread` will create a new thread.

In my case, there is an input stream that takes values from somewhere and the value is taken as an input. Some calculations are performed and the result is inserted into a result channel. In short, we have input and out put channel, and the calculation is done in the loop. So as to achieve concurrency, I have two choices, either use a go-block or use `thread`.

I wonder what is the intrinsic difference between these two. (We may assume there is no I/O during the calculations.) The sample code looks like the following:

```clj
(go-loop []
  (when-let [input (<! input-stream)]

  ... ; calculations here

  (>! result-chan result))
  (recur))

(thread
  (loop []
    (when-let [input (<!! input-stream)]

    ...  ; calculations here

    (put! result-chan result))
    (recur)))
```

I realize the number of threads that can be run simultaneously is exactly the number of CPU cores. Then in this case, is go-block and `thread` showing no differences if I am creating more than 8 `thread` or go-blocks?

I might want to simulate the differences in performance in my own laptop, but the production environment is quite different from the simulated one. I could draw no conclusions.

By the way, the calculation is not so heavy. If the inputs are not so large, 8,000 loops can be run in 1 second.

Another consideration is whether go-block vs `thread` will have an impact on GC performance.

Comment: Tools not rules, but if you insist on a rule: use the go-block.

Comment: Threads are simpler and more bulletproof.  The JVM can support over 1000 threads on modern hardware w/o problem.  The primary strength of core.async is that it can *simulate* multithreading in the browser, which has only one thread that must be shared.  I would rarely consider it a first choice on the JVM.

Comment: @AlanThompson serious question: for concurrency needs that aren't computationally heavy (e.g. simple IO) isn't core.async preferable? As for simplicity it's somewhat in the eye of the beholder: I find CSP pretty intuitive but YMMV. Every time I've ever used threads in an application (caveat: have only done so in Python and C) it wound up being more complicated, more error prone, and less testable than CSP would have been.

Comment: "(caveat: have only done so in Python and C)"....that is your answer.  On the JVM, with immutable data structure of Clojure, they are MUCH simpler.  Even in pure Java it's not too bad if you stick to immutable data.  The weakness of go-loops is that they are a Clojure *simulation* of multithreading, limited by what you can do in a macro (much more primitive than what a full compiler + virtual machine can do).  The best way to understand is implement various algorithms using both threads & go-loops.

Comment: For your example, I would kick off a short-lived thread using `future`.

Comment: If you're talking about `thread` (with a lower case `t`) from `core.async` it doesn't start a new thread. It uses the same executor as the `go` blocks. You can use `java.lang.Thread` to start a new thread. However, there are other options. What you're describing sounds like the sort of thing transducers were designed to solve. If you wrote the calculations in a less imperative style, rather than use loop/recur you could use something like `core.async/pipeline`.

Comment: sorry - I meant `thread` uses an exector service like the `go` blocks, not the same one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to note here.

Firstly, the thread pool that threads are created on via clojure.core.async/thread is what is known as a cached thread pool, meaning although it will re-use recently used threads inside that pool, it's essentially unbounded. Which of course means it could potentially hog a lot of system resources if left unchecked.

But given that what you're doing inside each asynchronous process is very lightweight, threads to me seem a little overkill. Of course, it's also important to take into account the quantity of items you expect to hit the input stream, if this number is large you could potentially overwhelm core.async's thread pool for go macros, potentially to the point where we're waiting for a thread to become available.

You also didn't mention preciously where you're getting the input values from, are the inputs some fixed data-set that remains constant at the start of the program, or are inputs continuously feed into the input stream from some source over time?

If it's the former then I would suggest you lean more towards transducers and I would argue that a CSP model isn't a good fit for your problem since you aren't modelling communication between separate components in your program, rather you're just processing data in parallel.

If it's the latter then I presume you have some other process that's listening to the result channel and doing something important with those results, in which case I would say your usage of go-blocks is perfectly acceptable.